# How do I handle System Management.Automation.ParameterBindingArgumentTransformationException

Tags: powershell, foreach, exception, path, migration

Please help. I am stuck with some exception handling.  I have files that I must read and make small changes to. however there are instances where the required file is not found and in that case, I will move on to look for the next file. But before all this happens I am getting this error `2017-07-25 12:19:25 [PS-Error]: (file_migration.ps1) (Invoke-MainScript) Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'Path'. Cannot convert value to type System.String.`

The error is pointing to this function `Remove-TableOfContents -Path $FilePath`.  Here is the code I wrote for this function.

```
Function Remove-TableOfContents
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
        [string]$Path,

        [string]$Macro = $Script:RegexTocMacro
    )
    $FileContent = Get-Content -Path $Path
    $FileContent = $FileContent -replace $Macro, ''
    IF([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($Path))
    {
        Invoke-MainScript            
    }
    Set-Content -Path $Path -Value $FileContent
    Get-Content $FileContent | Where-Object {$_ -match $Path} | Invoke-MainScript


}
```

I have checked around and read a lot but I am not finding a solution to get past this problem. Any help with this will be appreciated.

Comment: What is `Invoke-MainScript` and what does it's `param()` block look like?

Comment: @Mathias R. Jessen Invoke-MainScript is the main function running the script and it looks like this `Function Invoke-MainScript
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param()`

Comment: What value is being passed in `$Filepath`? Can you show the code where you call `Remove-TableOfContents`?

Comment: @Benh Yes here is the code `Function Invoke-MainScript
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param()
    try
    {
        $Pages = Get-ChildItem -Path $PageDir -Directory      
      foreach($Page in $Pages)
        {
            $Path = Get-FilePath -Path $Page
            Remove-TableOfContents -Path $Path
       }
    }catch
    catch
    {

    }
}`The  value being passed into the file path is C:\Users\username\Documents\files

Comment: So then the question becomes what's returned by `Get-FilePath` as that's what you are passing. Can you show that function?

Comment: @BenH I just noticed there is nothing being returned. it just appears with an equal sign when debugging. Possibly that is where the issue is.